# Python/Tkinter - Change the Text Color Of on a Checkbox, When Checkbox is Checked?

Tags: python, checkbox, text, tkinter, colors

As the title suggests... Is there a way to change the color of the text on a checkbox while the checkbox is checked, and then return to the default color when the checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , You do can change the color of the text when the `Checkbutton` is on. To change the color of the text, option `fg` is used. I have made two variables `off_color` and `on_color`. When the `Checkbutton` is off, the color of text is `red` button when it is on , the color is `green`.
Here is a code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
root = Tk()
off_color = "red"
on_color = "green"
def on_check():    #this function will run on click on checkbutton
    if cbVar.get() == "1":chbox["fg"] = on_color     # if (get current checkbutton state) is "1" then....
    else:chbox["fg"] = off_color
cbVar = StringVar(root)     #making variable for checkbutton
cbVar.set(0)          #turning off the checkbutton (initialy)
chbox = Checkbutton(root,variable = cbVar,text="Check me",command=on_check,fg=off_color)     #making the checkbutton
chbox.place(x=0,y=0)         #placing the checkbutton
mainloop()
```

When the `checkbutton` is off:
[image: Off]

When the `checkbutton` is on:
[image: On]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking... What does 'cb.Var.set(0)' do? Does it ensure the checkbox is off on startup?

Comment: @Est `cb.Var.set(0)` turn off the check button.